# Why in python I'm getting IndexError: index 22 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep on getting IndexError: index 22 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22 and I dont' know why. I looked it up and they didn't tell me anything that was applicable to my situation.

My code:

```
import cv2
from grip import GripPipeline
import sys

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',1)
p = GripPipeline()
p.process(img)
print(p.filter_contours_output)
max = -sys.maxsize - 1
picstuff = [[0 for x in range(0, 2)] for y in range(0,len(p.filter_contours_output))] 
for i in range(0, len(p.filter_contours_output)):
for j in range(0, len(p.filter_contours_output[i])):
    print("x: " + str(p.filter_contours_output[i][j][0][0]) + " y: " + str(p.filter_contours_output[i][j][0][1]))
    for k in range(0, len(p.filter_contours_output)):
        for l in range(0, len(p.filter_contours_output[i])):
            if(p.filter_contours_output[i][j][0][0] == p.filter_contours_output[k][l][0][0]):
                temp = p.filter_contours_output[k][l][0][1] - p.filter_contours_output[i][j][0][1]
                if(temp > max):
                    max = temp
                    picstuff[i][0] = p.filter_contours_output[i][j][0]
                    picstuff[i][1] = p.filter_contours_output[k][l][0]
```

print(picstuff)

Comment: Tuples and lists start at zero, not one. The indicies for something size 22 are 0-21 inclusive.

Comment: at which line are you receiving the error?

Comment: show the full error output